# What to do if you are offended by someone on this site?

Tags: support

I do not want to name names at this point, but there was a recent comment in response to an (automated) comment from the low-quality post queue, which really went to my nerves. And this comment almost made me lose my temper.
In general I would like to know how to deal with a situation like this. Fortunately, the last time that happened is already long ago and I was quite new to this site. That is why I cannot remember how this matter was dealt with. And I do not know how to search for it on meta - my tries have not brought up anything.

If necessary I will bring up the offence, but for now I would rather like to keep it general.

Comment: `flag>it is offensive, abusive or hate speech`, the rest moderators will look into

Comment: Accept the fact that offensive remarks are apart of the internet.

Comment: I agree with you Martin - the comment you are referring to is offensive. I have also had a few borderline offensive/unhelpful comments from the same person. I agree that flagging if it is offensive is the right thing to do. Unfortunately, it is easier to be rude on the internet than in person, and some people take advantage of that.

Comment: In two of the ("milder") cases the comments were part of the discussion so I could not mark the comment flags as helpful or it would have purged them from the rolls and the conversation would not have made sense.  Please know that flagging is the right way to go here, this exception is just a quirk of the system.

Comment: Haters gonna hate. ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Flagging the comment is the best way to go for immediate removal.  Honestly, though, in cases like this, go ahead and also flag the question or answer that the comment is associated with so we have a more permanent record of it.

The situation has now been dealt with.

Comment: I don't know if Martin did, but I flagged this when it came up for review.

Comment: @Geoff Thanks.  I'm on mobile so I will be able to check on it in a bit

Comment: @Geoff Thanks, a lot and Jonsca, too, for all the support.